# Python; call function in X seconds unless event happens

Tags: python, multithreading

I have Python code controlling a robot. I order it to turn its motors, which should cause a real life event to occur. If within 5 seconds nothing happens (no POST request is sent, in this case), I want a second set of motors to turn to prompt an action. If the request is received, cancel the impending timer. If the timer hits 5 and the prompting function is called, set up another timer in case it needs more prompting. This is my pseudocode:

```
rotateMotor(BP.PORT_B, -360)
timer = Timer(5, promptEvent())
timer.start()

def eventReceiver():
    timer.cancel()
    rotateMotor(BP.PORT_B, -360)
    timer.start()

def promptEvent():
    rotateOtherMotors()
    timer.start()
```

My problem is that I get the error `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`. Fair enough, except I'm not experienced enough in Python to know how to do threads to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you are starting the timer twice which would not be a good idea. you might want to use a second timer if you really need 2 time counters

```
rotateMotor(BP.PORT_B, -360)
timer = Timer(5, promptEvent()) // first timer.start() (or time-wise second)
timer.start() // second timer.start() (or time-wise first)
```

added:

ok it seems that you want a timing tool and `Timer` which inherits from `Thread` is a non-reusable object. you either [alter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433394/calling-thread-timer-more-than-once) the `Timer` object or you may want to change the way you execute the code into the **simplified** example below:

```
while motor_needs_to_turn:
    starting_time = time.time()
    rotateMotor(BP.PORT_B, -360)
    while time.time() - starting_time < 5:
        if event_triggered: // request received
            starting_time = time.time()
            rotateMotor(BP.PORT_B, -360)
    rotateOtherMotors()
```

Comment: I don't need 2 timers, I need N timers, since I'm doing a sequence of 'motors rotating' -> 'expected event' -> 'motors rotating' -> 'expected event', for quite a few loops. What I need is a way to basically call another function (the promptEvent()) if I haven't seen 'expected event' in 5 seconds of the 'motors rotating'.