# Starting the same thread twice

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

I want to start the same timer twice so I can stop that same timer. When I try this:

```
    thread = threading.Timer(period_sec, method, list(args))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    thread.start()
```

I get `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`
Is there way to do so?

**EDITED**

I want to create a repeating timer. I need to use the same thread so I can call `cancel` to the same registered thread. Here is example code:

```
class TestThreading:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.text = "t"

        self.threads = dict()
        self.thread_id = 1

    def method_1(self):
        print self.number
        self.number += 1

    def method_2(self, text):
        print self.text
        self.text += text

    def register_periodic_thread(self, method, period_sec, *args):
        thread_name = method.__name__ + "_" + str(self.thread_id)
        current_thread = threading.Timer(period_sec, method, list(args))
        current_thread.run()
        self.thread_id += 1
        self.threads[thread_name] = current_thread
        return thread_name

    def start_periodic_thread(self, thread):
        print thread
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        print thread

    def stop_periodic_thread(self, thread):
        thread.cancel()

    def get_periodic_thread(self, thread_mame):
        if thread_mame in self.threads:
            return self.threads[thread_mame]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestThreading()
    task_id = test.register_periodic_thread(test.method_1, 1)
    task = test.get_periodic_thread(task_id)
    test.start_periodic_thread(task)

    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    test.stop_periodic_thread(task)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you 'join' then expect to start the thread again? You cannot start a timer twice, and you haven't provided a reason why you want to.

Comment: Is this maybe what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433394/calling-thread-timer-more-than-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use delegation since python doesn't appear to have a default implementation.

```
from threading import Timer
import time

class RepeatingTimer:
    def __init__(self, period, method, args):
        self.stopped = False
        self.args = args
        self.method = method
        self.period = period
        self.task = None

    def schedule(self):
        if not self.stopped:
            self.task = Timer(self.period, self.run, [])
            self.task.start()
    def run(self):
        if not self.stopped:
            self.method(*self.args)
            self.schedule()
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
        if self.task:
            self.task.cancel()
            self.task.join()

    def start(self):
        self.schedule()

def something(a, b):
    print(a + b)

timmy = RepeatingTimer(0.5, something, (5,6))
timmy.start()

time.sleep(1)
timmy.stop()
```

That way, at the end of the task, a new task is schedule. Unless the timer has been stopped.

Also, it could be arranged so that this can be restarted.